# Block downloading by Content-Type via Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-headers

I am developing an extension for blocking downloading by file's Content-Type. This is part of background script which handle headers receiving:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
    var headers = details.responseHeaders;

    for(var i = 0, l = headers.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if(headers[i].name == "Content-Type" && headers[i].value == "<some_type>") {
            return {cancel: true};
        }
    }
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["responseHeaders", "blocking"]);
```

And I get page with error message:
[image: message]

So I need some solution to keep user on previous page without reloading to displaying this error page OR somehow move back from this service page after it displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to prevent navigating away in an (i)frame based on the content type, then you're out of luck - it is not possible to prevent a page from unloading at this point.

If you want to prevent the top-level frame from navigating away, then there's hope. You can redirect the page to a resource that replies with HTTP status code 204.

```js
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
    // ... your code that checks whether the request should be blocked ...

    if (details.frameId === 0) { // Top frame, yay!
        var scheme = /^https/.test(details.url) ? "https" : "http";
        chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {
            url: scheme + "://robwu.nl/204"
        });
        return;
    }
    return {cancel: true};
}, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
}, ["responseHeaders", "blocking"]);
```

Once [issue 280464](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=280464) is solved, the previous method can also be used to prevent unloads in subframes.

https://robwu.nl/204 is part of my website. Access to this URL is not logged. The response to this entry will always be "204 No Content".

Comment: @RobW the given solution is not preventing the download, using just "return" causes the download to start.

Comment: @adnankamili To fix that issue, you could change the `content-type` header to something non-downloadable text/plain, add `content-type-options: no-sniff` (to disable MIME-sniffing). Though honestly, this answer is a real hack. If your intent is to cancel a request, then you should really be using `{cancel: true}`.

Comment: @RobW Still no luck, I can't use {cancel: true} because it causes that block page to appear. I tried return {redirectUrl: ""};, this prevents the weblock page but the function does not return and extension keeps on waiting. Can you suggest some other hack as I need it desperately.

Comment: `redirectUrl` is not supported yet (though I'm working on an implementation, see http://crbug.com/280464#4 for details). Further, a bug in Chromium prevented the request from completing when you supply it (see http://crbug.com/348417, fixed in Chrome 35). My previously suggested hack (modifying the headers to use `Content-Type: text/plain` and `X-Content-Options: nosniff`) should work. If it didn't, then you need to show your code.

Comment: @RobW I have opened a new question with code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593735/how-to-prevent-download-on-recieving-response-headers-in-chrome-extension also tried a hack involving change in response line 302 Moved Temporarily but it didn'work